# How do I target a element in an array made through an axios.get request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im trying to create a label that will display a status that changes over time. I have a database that has all the statuses, its just a matter of creating a react component that will output the status. I just need to output one and Im trying to do that by targeting the specific portion in an array, but it's giving me a the following error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    drought_status: [],
    drought_id: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => {
      console.log(res);

      this.setState({ drought_status: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UncontrolledDropdown>
          <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>

          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem>{this.state.drought_status[0].name}</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `drought_status` array is empty before your request is complete, so `this.state.drought_status[0]` will be `undefined`, and trying to access `name` on that will give rise to your error.

You could check that `this.state.drought_status[0]` is set before you try to access `name`.

**Example**

```
render() {
  const firstDroughtStatus = this.state.drought_status[0];

  return (
    <div>
      <UncontrolledDropdown>
        <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          {firstDroughtStatus ? (
            <DropdownItem>{firstDroughtStatus.name}</DropdownItem>
          ) : null}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what does 

{firstDroughtStatus ? ( 

Do in this case?

Comment: @AhmedZaher If `firstDroguhtStatus` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), we know that `this.state.drought_status[0]` is not `undefined`, so we can assume the array has loaded. If `firstDroughtStatus` is still `undefined`, we render `null` instead.

Comment: nvm looked it up. Sorry to bother you I appreciate the help. I didnt understand that this was how you would use that operator.

Comment: @AhmedZaher No problem.